# Group JavaScript Array Items on their Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Group javascript array items on value

Assuming you have a json object like:

```
[
  {
    prNumber: 20000401,
    text: 'foo'
  },
  {
    prNumber: 20000402,
    text: 'bar'
  },
  {
    prNumber: 20000401,
    text: 'foobar'
  },
]
```

Is it possible to perform a "join" on prNumber?

For example, maybe the desired output would be something like:

```
[
  {
    prNumber: 20000401,
    text: [
      'foo',
      'foobar'
    ]
  },
  {
    prNumber: 20000402,
    text: [
      'bar'
    ]
  }
]
```

I have no code samples worth anything, so I will not post them here.

This would preferrably use vanilla javascript, but will accept a jQuery answer.

Comment: Please add [**your current code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are having issues with so we can help you figure out why it is not working. Adding a [**fiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) demonstrating your current issue would also help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should iterate the initial array and create new objects keyed off the `prNumber`. Here's how to do it using `reduce` (assuming you've assigned the array to a variable named `orig`):

```
var result = orig.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, arr) {
    var num = curr["prNumber"];
    if (!prev[num]) {
        prev[num] = [];
    }
    prev[num].push(curr["text"]);
    return prev;
}, {});
```

You can easily convert this into the example structure outlined in your question.