# How do I group muiltiple record in array to object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

hope everyone doing well!

Is there anyone in here who can help how to group the below array to object **sort** by the **second** item of each record in Javascript?

i.e: `"{first},{second},{third},{fourth}"` -> "bob,627,1973,Amsterdam"

Take for example this array:

```
[
  'bob,627,1973,amsterdam',
  'alice,387,885,bangkok',
  'alice,355,1029,barcelona',
  'alice,587,402,bangkok',
  'charlie,973,830,barcelona',
  'alice,932,86,bangkok',
  'bob,188,989,amsterdam'
];
```

expected result:

```
{
  alex: [
    [ 355, '1029', 'barcelona' ],
    [ 387, '885', 'bangkok' ],
    [ 587, '402', 'bangkok' ],
    [ 932, '86', 'bangkok' ],
  ],
  bob: [ 
    [ 188, '989', 'amsterdam' ],
    [ 627, '1973', 'amsterdam' ],
  ],
  charlie: [
    [ 973, '830', 'barcelona' ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group JavaScript Array Items on their Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117251/group-javascript-array-items-on-their-value) - You can split the items by using `.split(',')`

Comment: Then it's a matter of reducing the array to an object.

Comment: Question is closed, but FWIW: https://jsfiddle.net/05d3xpuz/

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried your approach and it worked! Thanks in advance Tim! Meanwhile I already find a better approach for the code to be more readable using groubBy function by lodash.